# Booting Ubuntu Mate to Repair Windows and Fix BSOD PAGE FAULT in NON-PAGED AREA

Tags: ubuntu, bsod

Good tidings everyone

I have been assisting my friend and attempted to repair his windows. This is a time-line and a description of what steps have been taken to resolve the error PAGE FAULT in NON-PAGED AREA:

Restored windows to a prior version. Problems: Windows update didn't work and thusly we tried using sfc /scannow, but it failed, not before breaking windows update though. We could not use DISM as it would likely fail since windows update was broken.

Then we downloaded a new image file with the media creation tool and used it to upgrade windows. We are aware that we should have used it with DISM to restore the image file on windows and then hopefully fix the BSOD error.

At this stage windows has been upgraded, but the installation failed and left a defaultuser0 which we couldn't remove. We powered down and removed the RAM sticks and tried different combinations, but nothing worked. Next we disabled memory cache, but that didn't help either.

So after trying this we tried erasing the hdd and reinstall windows. We are now stuck in an endless BSOD loop. PAGE FAULT in NON-PAGED AREA.

We now create a live bootable USB with Ubuntu Mate. PC boots into it and we run ntfsfix with clear dirty flags and fix bad sectors and it seems to work. At least we are getting confirmation that it did find a corrupted NTFS file volume, but when next we boot windows it's still stuck in an endless BSOD.

Comment: I'm just as interested in this from the perspective of learning more about computers, so if anyone has a "big brain" solution or explanation, then I'm all ears.